# Extraxt a specific field from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am having a list in python. I would like to extract the field **countryRegion** only. How am I supposed to do that. The code `lst['countryRegion']` procduces the error : ***TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str***.

Help me please

```
 [{'__type': 'Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
  'address': {'adminDistrict': 'Tamil Nadu',
   'adminDistrict2': 'Chennai',
   'countryRegion': 'India',
   'formattedAddress': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
   'locality': 'Chennai'},
  'bbox': [12.85071, 79.97689, 13.23403, 80.33292],
  'confidence': 'High',
  'entityType': 'PopulatedPlace',
  'geocodePoints': [{'calculationMethod': 'None',
    'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186],
    'type': 'Point',
    'usageTypes': ['Display']}],
  'matchCodes': ['Good'],
  'name': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
  'point': {'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186], 'type': 'Point'}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your input

```
lst =  [{'__type': 'Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
  'address': {'adminDistrict': 'Tamil Nadu',
   'adminDistrict2': 'Chennai',
   'countryRegion': 'India',
   'formattedAddress': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
   'locality': 'Chennai'},
  'bbox': [12.85071, 79.97689, 13.23403, 80.33292],
  'confidence': 'High',
  'entityType': 'PopulatedPlace',
  'geocodePoints': [{'calculationMethod': 'None',
    'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186],
    'type': 'Point',
    'usageTypes': ['Display']}],
  'matchCodes': ['Good'],
  'name': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
  'point': {'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186], 'type': 'Point'}}]
```

you get your data from

```
lst[0]['address']['countryRegion']
```

- First, TypeError is due to `lst` being a list type and not Dictionary type
- Second, `countryRegion` is not a key of your dictionary, but inside the dictionary value from key `address`

Answer (score 1):

It is producing that error because of the list containing a single element that is of type dictionary.

so to access the desired value you can just use the command

```
list_dic = [{'__type': 'Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
'address': {'adminDistrict': 'Tamil Nadu',
   'adminDistrict2': 'Chennai',
   'countryRegion': 'India',
   'formattedAddress': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
   'locality': 'Chennai'},
  'bbox': [12.85071, 79.97689, 13.23403, 80.33292],
  'confidence': 'High',
  'entityType': 'PopulatedPlace',
  'geocodePoints': [{'calculationMethod': 'None',
    'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186],
    'type': 'Point',
    'usageTypes': ['Display']}],
  'matchCodes': ['Good'],
  'name': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
  'point': {'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186], 'type': 'Point'}}]
  
   lst_dic[0]['address']['countryRegion']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is a list of dictionary.

I dont know how you obtain the json but here's what i was able to get:

```
js=[{'__type': 'Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1',
  'address': {'adminDistrict': 'Tamil Nadu',
   'adminDistrict2': 'Chennai',
   'countryRegion': 'India',
   'formattedAddress': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
   'locality': 'Chennai'},
  'bbox': [12.85071, 79.97689, 13.23403, 80.33292],
  'confidence': 'High',
  'entityType': 'PopulatedPlace',
  'geocodePoints': [{'calculationMethod': 'None',
    'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186],
    'type': 'Point',
    'usageTypes': ['Display']}],
  'matchCodes': ['Good'],
  'name': 'Chennai, Tamil Nadu',
  'point': {'coordinates': [13.07209, 80.20186], 'type': 'Point'}}]
  
for i in range(len(js)):
    print(js[i]["address"]["countryRegion"])
```